# Java, What would be an efficient way to save data with multiple attributes?

Tags: java, save

Okay, so I'm not entirely sure ho to ask this or search for an answer for this so I'm going to give an example.

Lets say I run a company that makes cups. Each different cup is a different color, made of a different material and can be different sizes. Suppose I want to make a program that can be used to keep track of all of the different cups and save it so it can be used later. For example:

Big Red Cup - Color:Red, Size:12oz, material:plastic

So, in java if I wanted to allow the user to create as many items like this one and save them what an efficient way of doing this?

Sorry I'm not too experienced so sorry if this seems vague or if it's a bad question but any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked to see if a database system would suite your application ? If its very simplistic application and you just want to get the hang of Java consider writing the output to a text file in a specific format of your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need certainly --- (drum roll) a *class*!

Classes in Java is used to store a bunch of data in one place. (This is one of its use at least) You can create different *objects* of a class.

Your `Cup` class would probably look like this:

```
public class Cup {
    public Color color;
    public int size;
    public Material material;

    //Constructor
    public Cup (Color color, int size, Material material) {
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        this.material = material;
    }
}
```

`Color` and `Material` are *enums*. They probably look like this:

```
public enum Color {
    Red, Green, Blue // Of course you an add other colors
}

public enum Material {
    Wood, Glass, Plastic //Of course you an add others
}
```

And you can create a Big Red Cup using this:

```
Cup bigRedCup = new Cup (Color.Red, 15, Material.Plastic);
```

And you can refer to the cup's attributes by:

```
bigRedCup.color
bigRedCup.size
bigRedCup.material
```

You can also add getter and setter methods in your cup class to add some encapsulation.

More about classes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Comment: Thanks man. I just wasn't sure about how to set up the different objects of the class and how to use the enums for the different attributes. Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose the thing you're asking for is a [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure). An array would not be the optimal choice for your program cause you're saying you want to have the user as many as he wants and hence the data structure has to be dynamic, however arrays in Java have a fixed size, that has to be determined at compile time. I'd suggest you to take a look at the Java API implementation of a [Linked List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/),  which offers you all possibilities you need. It's dynamic and you can easily add, clear, remove things with little effort.

If you're searching for "offline saving methods", I'd suggest you to store all the stuff in a database, so take a look at MySQL and the [JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j) for mysql in Java. It provides you various methods to handle your database.